# What does "Warning: mail (): 1" mean when calling "mail ()" in PHP?

Tags: php, email, warnings

I have a website on the host "free.fr" and when I want to call the "mail ()" in PHP function to send a simple mail, a warning appears and I do not receive any mail ...

Here is my code:

```
$headers = "From: mysite@free.fr \r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';

mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'sujet', 'message');
```

The warning displayed:

```
Warning: mail(): 1 in /var/www/sda/7/5/mysitefreefr/test-mail.php on line 5
```

The warning in itself doesn't bother me but I didn't receive the email ... so I imagine it's related :(

I don't understand this message "**mail (): 1**" and I can't find any explanation on google ... thank you :)

Ps: using the call "error_get_last () ['message']" I also have the same warning that appears.

Comment: FYI: You're mentioning headers, but are not passing them to `mail()` according to this code.

Comment: I would try to send to another email. 
The email could end in the spam folder or be refused by the server because for example the header is missing
You can also check the result in the following way

$mailok = mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'sujet', 'message', $headers);
if (!$mailok) ...